Equivalence of Hamiltonianity and Eulerianity for particular graphs
I was studying graph theory when a question came to my mind.
Let's first recall some definitions. A graph is a set of vertices equipped with a set of arcs, each of which can be thought as a set of exactly two vertices (so no loops, no oriented arcs and no multiple arcs between the same two vertices). A path in a graph is a finite sequence of adjacent vertices (i.e. the arc between every two consecutive vertices belongs to the graph) such that, if two occurrences coincide, the following ones do not coincide (i.e. no repeated arcs). A circuit in a graph is a path in which the first and the last vertices coincide. A path is simple if it has no repeated vertices, except, possibly, its first and last ones. A cycle is a simple circuit. A graph is Hamiltonian if it admits a Hamiltonian cycle, i.e. a cycle in which every vertex appears at least once. A graph is Eulerian if it admits a Eulerian circuit, i.e. a circuit in which every couple of adjacent vertices appears consecutively in the sequence or, equivalently, in which every arc appears at least once.
It is possible to find examples of graphs which are Hamiltonian and not Eulerian an vice versa. My question is the following: are there particular classes of graphs (as defined above) for which Hamiltonianity and Eulerianity are equivalent, i.e. one of its graph is Hamiltonian if and only if it is Eulerian?

Trivially, the cycle graphs (which are all Hamiltonian and Eulerian) or the star graphs (which are all non-Hamiltonian and non-Eulerian). I assume you want some other family where both occur?

@JaapScherphuis Thank you for your examples. I only add that in the case of star graphs, their being non-Hamiltonian and non-Eulerian can be viewed as a consequence of their being trees, i.e. not having circuits at all, so trees have more in general those properties. For the rest, yes, I was implicitly referring to classes large enough to display both instances, better if equipped with explicit characterisations of Hamiltonianity (lacking in the general case).

It seems that when you allow the degree of vertices to be higher than 3 you are bound to encounter problems for Eulerianity. So I guess every non-hamiltonian graph with a vertex of degree at least 3 related to what you seek

@Qise For instance, complete graphs are all Hamiltonian, but are Eulerian if and only if they have an odd number of vertices (by one of the many Euler's theorems). This may be an answer to my question. Anything else?
